# Does FB ads track actual installation or just an "install" button click?

Tags: facebook

I'm about to use Facebook to advertise my app.

Here's my question, for data tracking in FB analytics: Is this data the actual app installation? Or is it just how many people click on "Install" button?

Answer (score 1):

In order to track installs you need to integrate the Facebook SDK or use an SDK of one of the Mobile Measurement Partners.

See the [Mobile Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads#advanced) guide.